# Cancel search in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code

If i try search something in vs code it works fine but even after it has found the result i am looking for it continues to search, which is not ideal because i think it is searching everything in the `node-modules` folder, which depending on my search term, with freeze vs code completely.

I know i could probably just regex the `node-modules` folder out of the search, but its so simple as it is , it always finds the results quickly but then just hangs. Don't know if i have maybe overlooked something in the editor but is there a simple stop on searching?

Comment: *** ***`Esc?`*** ***

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just press <kbd>esc</kbd> to stop the search

Here's the default [keybinding](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings) for that:

```
{
     "key": "escape",
     "command": "search.action.cancel",
     "when": "listFocus && searchViewletVisible"
}
```